# capybara within :css syntax meaning

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

I'm currently working on fixing up some specs, and have found a piece of syntax that nobody seems to know what represents.

In the Capybara Suite there are multiple occurrences of:

`within(:css, '#foo') do`

By removing the `:css` I have found this to be functionally identical to `within('#foo') do`

Is there a difference? What other symbols can be passed in as a first parameter to within?

Comment: Read the RDoc for [`within`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#within-instance_method)

Answer (score 0):

After following @Andrey Botalov's link, I have found that this explains which kind of selector is being input into the within block.

In my case, `Capybara.default_selector` was set to `:css`, so `:css` was default. The only other option listed is `:xpath`

Comment: There are many other selector types besides those - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L93

Comment: Most of those options aren't documented in Rubydocs as it's hard to document everything

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just repetitive code...unless theyre looking within acss for some text. But the better way to do thatwould be to say element.should.include? ('Text') and then set element equal tosome page.find (.css).
But if youre asking what a within block does, it just scopes the test down. Ex: 
within ('.facebooklogin') do 
   element.click
End